# Progressive Web App not in the root folder

Tags: javascript, ssl, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I am building an offline first app using service workers. I am almost done but I have a question on deploying the pwa.

*Scenario*:

The app is a small piece of a huge system so I cannot deploy on root / folder like on `www.mysite.com` because that is where the main site is running. I have to deploy on *e.g.* `www.mysite.com/offlineapp/`. The main app is built with PHP while I have built the `PWA` mainly with `Javascript`.

Will the app install successfully given that `mysite.com` is on https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are keeping your service-worker file at root location, then set scope while registering that to limit to a particular /offlineapp

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {
  scope: '/offlineapp/'
});
```

This will prevent service-worker from controling requests other than of /offlineapp/ like /offlineapp,/,/offlineapp2/etc

Comment: Makes sense. That is exactly what I want to avoid. It works.